# How can I save multiple figures individually from a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, obspy

I have this for-loop which shoots out focal mechanisms as a figures and I want to be able to save each figure individually but can't figure out how.

```
for strike,dip,rake in zip(out_df.strike,out_df.dip,out_df.rake):
     fig, ax = mplstereonet.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
     plt.rcParams["axes.labelsize"]=14
     bball = beachball.beach([strike, dip, rake]
          , width=433            # scale of the beachball in the (x,y) plane
          , linewidth=1             # thickness of nodal planes and beachball edge lines
          , facecolor='darkblue'    # color of one of the axes
          , zorder=1 # make sure beachball plots on top
          , axes = ax)
     ax.add_collection(bball)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the code below should do what you want:

```
m = 0
for strike,dip,rake in zip(out_df.strike,out_df.dip,out_df.rake):
     m += 1
     fig, ax = mplstereonet.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
     plt.rcParams["axes.labelsize"]=14
     bball = beachball.beach([strike, dip, rake]
          , width=433            # scale of the beachball in the (x,y) plane
          , linewidth=1             # thickness of nodal planes and beachball edge lines
          , facecolor='darkblue'    # color of one of the axes
          , zorder=1 # make sure beachball plots on top
          , axes = ax)
     ax.add_collection(bball)
     plt.savefig(f"figure_{m}.png")
     plt.close()
```